# mod_rewrite adding php extension?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Last 2 days i'm trying to run some application on my computer (Ubuntu 11.10, Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu), PHP Version 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.1). It's created in PHP Smarty and it use rewrite rules. Everything works fine with links like:

```
localhost/news
```

it's correctly translated into

```
localhost/news.php
```

how it should be done. But the problem is with more complicated links like

```
localhost/message/inbox
```

it should be translated with rule:

```
RewriteRule ^messages/(.*)$ /messages.php?action=$1
```

But it doesn't work. I was trying to debug it. I've truned on logging in http.conf

```
RewriteLog "/home/krzysztofp/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

And what i can see is that in the begining there is

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2012:15:56:36 +0100] [krzysztofp/sid#7f8218546a30][rid#7f821837a0a0/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/engbook/] add path info postfix: /var/www/engbook/messages.php -> /var/www/engbook/messages.php/inbox
```

and then it's trying to match message.php

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2012:15:56:36 +0100] [krzysztofp/sid#7f8218546a30][rid#7f821837a0a0/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/engbook/] applying pattern '^messages/(.*)$' to uri 'messages.php/inbox'
```

Virtual Host:

```
<Directory /var/www/engbook>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

any idea why it's happening?

EDIT:
i have a problem to put all rewrite rules on stack so here they are:
http://pokazkod.pl/d52823d5f0d31ff26e1e29873383d2a2ceb216306a56b3aec1
none on them look suspicious to me :/

Comment: please post your rewrite rules

Comment: When you say it is not working, what do you mean?  You get an error?  You get the wrong page?  The wrong output? I used your rules and when I go to `/messages/inbox` it calls `messages.php?action=inbox` just fine.

Comment: and that's what i would expect with there rules but somehow it calls just messages.php without ?action=inbox. In messages.php there is switch statment on $_GET['action'] and i can see that variable $_GET is empty...
I think it's a problem with configuration of Apache but i can't find where the hell is it.

Comment: Probably a typo, but in your url you use `message`, and in you rewriterule `messages` (plural). Also adding `RewriteEngine On` could help.

Comment: yes, it's just typo
and ReWriteEngine On is already added in the begining .htaccess ...

Answer (score 8):

Try removing [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#multiviews)

```
<Directory /var/www/engbook>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: OP hasn't accepted this, but I've just had the same problem and removing MultiViews solved it, so cheers for the post.

Comment: Thanks @afanasy. It helped me to find out my rewrite rule problem